# Ошибка в Firefox при работе с API Яндекс Карт

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты, карты

Подключаю API карт Яндекса вот так:

```
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Карту показываю по клику на ссылке (разворачивается блок).

```
$('#map-[[+id]]-link').on("click", function(){
      
    if(!$(this).hasClass('visible')){
          ymaps.ready(init);
            function init(){
                var myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map-[[+id]]", {
                    center: [[[+tv.coord]]],
                    zoom: 15,
                });
                var myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([[[+tv.coord]]]);
                myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark1);
            }
         $(this).addClass('visible');     
      }
    return false;
});
```

[[+tv.coord]] и т.п. - плейсхолдеры, которые заменяются в html конкретными значениями.
Работает во всех браузерах, кроме Firefox. Последний выдает вот такую ошибку

> ReferenceError: init is not defined
> ymaps.ready(init);

Хотя проверяю в консоли: объект ymaps существует.

В чем может быть проблема?

Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, решил проблему сам.

Функцию нужно было описать перед вызовом.

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('visible')){
    function init(){
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map-[[+id]]", {
             center: [[[+tv.coord]]],
             zoom: 15,
         });
         var myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([[[+tv.coord]]]);
         myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark1);
     }
      ymaps.ready(init);

     $(this).addClass('visible');     
   }
```

Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь объяснить, почему так. В памяти вплывает что-то про scope и локальный контекст, но почему тогда работает в остальных браузерах?

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень простое решение от самого Яндекса:

```js
// Формируем div-контейнер карты
<div id="YMapsID" style="width: 450px; height: 350px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myMap;
    function init (ymaps) {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("YMapsID", {
            center: [55.87, 37.66],
            zoom: 10
        });
        ...
    }
</script>

// Сразу после загрузки API будет 
   вызвана функция init.
// На момент ее исполнения div-контейнер 
   карты уже будет готов.
<script src="https://...?load=package.full&lang=ru_RU&onload=init">
```